# I want to print an array of strings in vertical order, const myArr = ['Google', 'Dell','Atlas'];

Tags: javascript, arrays

It should be like, first Google will be printed vertically, then Dell then Atlas. I mean each letter of each of the words will get printed in a vertical manner. I did as follows:

```js
const myArr = ['Google', 'Dell', 'Atlas'];

function myPattern(arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(elem) {
    let line = "";
    elem.split('').forEach(function(item) {
      line += `${item} `;
    })
    console.log(line);
  });
}
myPattern(myArr);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print Words Vertically in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659930/print-words-vertically-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.from()` to generate an array with the length of the longest word. Then iterate the array of words, and take the character at the current index, or use a space as a fallback:

```js
const myPattern = arr => 
  // create an array using the length of the longest word
  Array.from({ length: Math.max(...arr.map(a => a.length)) }, (_, i) => {
    // iterate the words and take the character at place `i` (or a space) and join with a tab/spaces/etc...
    const s = arr.map(str => str[i] || ' ').join('\t')
    console.log(s) // log the string or return to generate an array
  })

const myArr = ['Google', 'Dell', 'Atlas'];

myPattern(myArr)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you if you wanted them to be displayed side-by-side (run it below):

```js
const myArr = ['Google', 'Dell', 'Atlas'];

// function to check if value is empty
function returnValue(value) {
  if (typeof value != 'undefined' && value.length > 0) {
      return " " + value + " ";
  }
  return "   ";
}

function myPattern(arr) {
  let arrLength = arr.length;
  let finished = false;
  let level = 0;
  
  do {
    let result = "";
    
    for(let i=0; i<arrLength; i++) {
       result += returnValue(arr[i][level]); 
    }
    
    let row = result.trim();
    
    if(row != "") {
      console.log(row);
    } else {
      finished = true;
    }
    
    level++;
  } while(!finished);
}

myPattern(myArr);
```